# go run/build not getting dependencies

Tags: go

`go run` and `go build` are not `get`ing dependencies.

What I did:

- I have done a go get of a package, it fetched it, and its dependencies, and build it. (all is good)
- I run its command-line example program. (all is good)
- I then created a new program based on this example, and `go run` it. (all is good)
- Then copied this example program, and `go run` it. ( get a dependency error ).

## Transcript

```
#↳ go version
go version go1.11.4 linux/amd64

#↳ echo $GOPATH
/home/????/+Files/workshops/programming/golang/gopath

#↳ go get -u github.com/cbroglie/mustache/...

#↳ cp -T $GOPATH/src/github.com/cbroglie/mustache/cmd/mustache/main.go my-mustache.go

#↳ go build -v my-mustache.go
my-mustache.go:8:2: cannot find package "github.com/spf13/cobra" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/spf13/cobra (from $GOROOT)
    /go/src/github.com/spf13/cobra (from $GOPATH)
```

I can see why it is not already installed: it was in a vendor sub-directory of the original source code. But why does it not install, when I build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first your `$GOPATH/bin` folder: a `go get -u github.com/cbroglie/mustache/...` should already have compiled and installed all relevant binaries in it.

The [README](https://github.com/cbroglie/mustache#installation) mentions:

> To install `mustache.go`, simply run `go get github.com/cbroglie/mustache/...`.

---

From the comments:

> It looks like the mustache package is installed and working.   However
> when I try to build the cli example, it needs another package, if I go
> get it then all is well, however I was expecting go build to install
> all needed packages.   Am I wrong?

`go build` itself won't install dependencies, so you need to go get it, or activate [go 1.11 modules](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules) and declare that dependencies in your new program modules.

Comment: It looks like the mustache package is installed and working. However when I try to build the cli example, it needs another package, if I `go get` it then all is well, however I was expecting `go build` to install all needed packages. Am I wrong?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I have edited my answer to address your question

Comment: Thanks: is go modules what the mustache package will have used to install its dependencies?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor no, it is still using an older alternative (https://github.com/cbroglie/mustache/blob/master/cmd/mustache/Gopkg.lock) with dep. (https://github.com/golang/dep)